# Trigger on Reset Password Action

Tags: authentication, flow

As of Winter '15 there is the possibility of Login Flows. I followed examples from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows) and successfully implemented Two-Factor-Auth.

Business request Two-Factor-Authentication only to be presented when the user has to enter a new password:

1. after registration (user received initial password via e-mail)
2. after password reset by admin (user received reset password)

For 1. the Login Flow can ask for LastLoginDate. For 2. I somehow need a user flag that would reflect that situation.

Question: Is there any user object field that reflects that the users password had been reset? If not, is there any possibility to hook on the password reset action via APEX and fill some custom field?

Comment: I have this same situation. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @ThaddeusWard: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Our solution we came up with is based on the following steps:

1. Create a flow plugin, that returns the last password change information from the user that is currently executing the flow.

   ```
   global class SMSPlug_Check_LPD implements Process.Plugin { 

     global Process.PluginDescribeResult describe() {
       Process.PluginDescribeResult result = new Process.PluginDescribeResult();
       result.tag = 'Identity';
       result.name = 'SMS Plugin Check LPC';
       result.description = 'Two factor authentication with SMS';
       result.inputParameters = new List<Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter> {
           new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('USERID', Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING, false)
       };
       result.outputParameters = new List<Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter> {
           new Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter('LPC', Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.DateTime)
       };
       return result;
     }

     global Process.PluginResult invoke(Process.PluginRequest request) {
       Map<String, Object> result = new Map<String, Object>();
       String USERID = (String)request.inputParameters.get('USERID');
       result.put('LPC', query_user(USERID));
       return new Process.PluginResult(result);
     }

     public Datetime query_user(String UserID) {
       AsAdmin aa = new AsAdmin();
       aa.UserID = USERID;
       aa.queryUser();
       return aa.LastPasswordChangeDate;
     }

   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   public without sharing class AsAdmin {
       public Datetime LastpasswordChangeDate  {get;set;}
       public String UserID {get;set;}

       public DateTime queryUser() {
           User[] users = [SELECT LastPasswordChangeDate,ID FROM User where ID =:UserID];
           if (users.size() > 0)
               LastpasswordChangeDate = users[0].LastPasswordChangeDate;
           return LastpasswordChangeDate;
       }

   }
   ```

   The trick is to add `without sharing` to the class. Otherwise the `LastPasswordChangeDate` field will not be accessible.
2. Add another custom field to the user object that keeps track, when the user successfully completed 2-factor-authentication the last time.
3. Compare both fields during the flow, if LastPasswordChange > Last2FactorAuth then let user do the 2FA again.

Hope that helps.